# Given that no 1 turned up at the first two throws, what is the probability that at least three throws will be necessary for a 1 or 6 to appear?

Tags: probability, dice

**Question**: A die is thrown as long as necessary for a 1 or a 6 to turn up. Given that no 1 turned up at the first two throws, what is the probability that at least three throws will be necessary?

**Answer**: $\frac{16}{25}$

**what I did**: 
Since the first 2, nothing turned up I assumed the probability was $\frac{4}{6}$ and for the 3rd try I assume it will show up so the probability is $\frac{2}{6}$ I then subtracted it to $1$ to get the probability since it says *at least three throws* but it yields a wrong value. Thank you for any help

$$1-\frac{4}{6}\frac{4}{6}\frac{2}{6}=\frac{23}{27}$$

Comment: What is an ace? Is that rolling a $1$? or two $1$s in a row? I've never heard that term

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee I assumed it is 1, never heard of it too

Comment: Pst:  You are given that an 'ace' does not occur on the first two throws, *however*, that does not mean that a six does not.

Comment: @GrahamKemp "Given that no ace turned up at the first two throws" Doesn't that imply that there were at least two throws? So, it does rule out the possibility of there being a six on the first throw, but it doesn't rule out the possibility of there being a six on the second throw .. right?

Comment: The wording of this question is a bit of a headache! We need help from the [English Language & Usage Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/), haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this question let us first find what is the probability that we don't meet the condition in three throws.
**Since we know there was no 1 in first two throws**(you didn't consider this) the probability of us failing in two moves is 
 $$P(Failure)= \frac{4}{6-1}.\frac{4}{6-1} $$
Now, As we need at least three throws we just have to ensure that it fails for two throws.
Hence,
      the required probability is,$$P(n)=P(Failure)=\frac{4.4}{5.5}=\frac{16}{25}=0.64$$

Answer (score 0):

The reason your answer is wrong is that you are ignoring the part that "no ace turned up at the first two throws". So we know that in the first 2 throws there was no ace (I assumed "ace" mean 1). So for those 2 first throws the probability should only cover no 6 appearing so it will be `4/5`.

So the overall probability will be:
`4/5 * 4/5 = 16/25`
Note that since the question wants "at least" 3 throws any number of throws equal or bigger than 3 is good and since the probability never occurring a 1 or 6 in infinite throws is 0 so the probability is equal to `16/25`.

Comment: Doesn't the fact that "no ace turned up at the first two throws" imply that there could not have been a $6$ on the first throw? Because if there was a $6$ on the first throw, then there wouldn't even have been a second throw! ("die is thrown as long as it is necessary for an ace or $6$ to show up")

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee Actually no, it only limits the sample space. What I mean is that the sequence (6,2,4) is still valid in sample space, it is just not desired.

Comment: Is it in the sample space? After the first $6$, the die is no longer rolled ... or maybe I am reading the question too literally?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee Maybe I could rephrase my answer like this: The sequences (6) or (4,6) are still valid in the sample space (since the only restriction is no 1 in the first 2 possible throws) and so their probability should be considered.

Comment: Im having some difficulties understanding when it says "did not show up" does that mean you alter the probability by removing it to the number of possible outcomes?

Comment: @Ralph You can think of it like "invalid in sample space" so the occurrence of 1 in the first 2 throws is invalid (think of it like it happens you should ignore it at all)

Comment: @Alithewise ohhh ok ok thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rephrase the question:   A die is thrown until a `1` or `6` show.   What is the probability of this happening on the third or later throw, when given that a `1` will not show on the first two throws?

Ie: What is the probability something other than a `1` or `6` show on the first two throws when guaranteed that a `1` will not?

Comment: Did you mean to make this a comment? But yes, I agree that the question needs to be rephrased